# What is the point of 'FieldSpecified' in WCF?

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services

Ive noticed that if a field is specified as being not mandatory, when we generate the proxy class it will also generate an associated '[fieldname]IsSpecified' boolean related to that field.
On using Fiddler to inspect the request, if the associated 'isSpecified' is set to false, this means that the field will not be sent over the wires.

I have two questions related to this

1.What is the point of this? Is it purely to minimize the amount of data being sent across the wire?

2.If no value is passed into a parameter on a webservice, WCF will use the default data type for it. In the case of a integer field, the default will be 0. So once inside the method how is it possible to tell if this 0 is generated from nothing being sent from the client for that field, or if they indeed sent over a 0?

Answer (score 4):

On your question 2, the `Specified` fields are not used *only* by the sending side. On the receiving side, the XML deserialiser will set the `Specified` fields according to the presence or absence of the corresponding fields on the wire, which allows the service methods to find out whether they were actually transmitted.

As for why you would want to do this apart from compactness of wire representation, an example I've seen is a service which allows you to update several fields in a record at once. In addition to setting the expected non-null values for fields, the service uses different wire representations for two special cases:

- *Update this field to null:* `<field1 xsi:nil="true" />`
- *Don't update this field:* The XML element is omitted altogether.